# How to ignore fields/methods in ParseObject subclass serialization?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a subclass of a ParseObject that has a JSONArray variable. I would like to implement a `toList` method for this variable that returns the values as a list

Comment: Which library are you using to do JSON object parsing?

Comment: I am using facebook's Parse, it returns an Array in the database as a JSONArray

Comment: Facebook parse provide you data but how are you doing parsing?

Comment: It's done automagically when you subclass `ParseObject`

Comment: Ok, Can you provide you Json response and expected class prototype here so we can identify your problem.

Comment: I don't get JSON resposes as it is serialized by the Parse framework itself into the ParseObject subclass

Comment: Ok, From parse Object what do you want to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136116/discussion-between-john-ernest-guadalupe-and-avi).

Comment: You can define Exclude policy in JsonSeriealizer and deserializer.

Comment: Let me provide you one example with GSON library. I am not sure how it will work in Facebook parser but you have to look for something similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Define a Annotation Exclude.

```
/**
 * To exclude a field in Gson
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Exclude {
}
```

Define Exclude Strategy:-

```
/**
 * To exclude a field in Gson
 */
public class ExcludeFieldStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can add Sereialization or deserialization exclusion statergy like this:-

```
addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExcludeFieldStrategy());
```

you need to figure out how you can provide Custom sereializer for facebook prase.

Apply annotation on Method or field of your ParserObject Class Like:-

```
class ParserObvect{
     @Exclude
     public String mExcludeObject;

     @Exclude
     public void toListString(String someData){
     }
}
```